# how to run 2 mysql servivce on 1 machine of win7 Operating system?

Tags: mysql

I have successfully made 2 mysql services on my win7 os using different port: 3306 and 3307. But the problem is : I cannot make them run at the same time. Any of them runs pretty good individually. When I try to turn the other service on while one is running, there would be a 1053 error.

just don't know why..

spent 2 days on this problem already .. no clue ..

Comment: have you checked the mysql server logs?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you missed a setting and both instances are trying to access the same data files. Please use [this manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-windows-command-line-servers.html) as a checklist.

Comment: I did check the checklist but failed. I dicide to give up windows now.